# pywin32 RuntimeError: Can't find the Windows SDK

Tags: python, pywin32

Execute "python setup3.py install" reported this error

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

```
D:\Software Package\pywin32-master\pywin32-master>python setup3.py install
Converting...
Executing...
Building pywin32 3.6.221.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup3.py", line 16, in <module>
    exec(str(got))
  File "<string>", line 305, in <module>
RuntimeError: Can't find the Windows SDK

D:\Software Package\pywin32-master\pywin32-master>python setup.py install
  File "setup.py", line 127
    print "Building pywin32", pywin32_version
                           ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
```

Comment: looks like a problem with the version of python. make sure the package can be installed in python 3. alternatively you can edit the file `setup.py` to eliminate the errors. i.e. change Line 127 to `print ("Building pywin32", pywin32_version)`

Comment: My fault, my default environment is 3.6.1 switch to 2.7 can be installed, but python3.6 really do not support it? Or my installation method is wrong?

Comment: could be an installation problem, try using pip if you have it setup i.e.`pip install pywin32 `. PS you may find https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662536/problem-installing-pywin32 useful

Comment: Clearly you're using *python2*. Use its full path in `${FULL_PYTHON3_PATH} setup3.py install`. However it would still need to build it so you need some additional tools installed. Or download the appropriate installer from https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20221